# jquery password validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

On my view i have 2 password fields:

```
   @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)<br />
   @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)<br />
```

Now i am looking for a way to use my javascript function below on these two fields.

```
function addCustomMessages() {
    $("#password_confirm").rules("add", {
        required: true,
        equalTo: "#password",
        messages: {
            required: "Herhaal uw wachtwoord",
            equalTo: "Enter the same password as above"
        }
    });
}
```

How can i tell  `@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)` it needs t use `#password-confirm`

**EDIT:**

View:

```
                   @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @id="password", @class = "equalTo" })<br />
                   @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @id="password_confirm", @class = "equalTo" })<br />
```

Javascript:

```
/*
 * Translated default messages for the jQuery validation plugin.
 * Locale: NL (Dutch; Nederlands, Vlaams)
 */
(function ($) {
    $.extend($.validator.messages, {
        required: "Dit is een verplicht veld.",
        remote: "Controleer dit veld.",
        email: "Vul hier een geldig e-mailadres in.",
        url: "Vul hier een geldige URL in.",
        date: "Vul hier een geldige datum in.",
        dateISO: "Vul hier een geldige datum in (ISO-formaat).",
        number: "Vul hier een geldig getal in.",
        digits: "Vul hier alleen getallen in.",
        creditcard: "Vul hier een geldig creditcardnummer in.",
        equalTo: "Vul hier dezelfde waarde in.",
        accept: "Vul hier een waarde in met een geldige extensie.",
        maxlength: $.validator.format("Vul hier maximaal {0} tekens in."),
        minlength: $.validator.format("Vul hier minimaal {0} tekens in."),
        rangelength: $.validator.format("Vul hier een waarde in van minimaal {0} en maximaal {1} tekens."),
        range: $.validator.format("Vul hier een waarde in van minimaal {0} en maximaal {1}."),
        max: $.validator.format("Vul hier een waarde in kleiner dan of gelijk aan {0}."),
        min: $.validator.format("Vul hier een waarde in groter dan of gelijk aan {0}."),

        // for validations in additional-methods.js
        iban: "Vul hier een geldig IBAN in.",
        dateNL: "Vul hier een geldige datum in.",
        phoneNL: "Vul hier een geldig Nederlands telefoonnummer in.",
        mobileNL: "Vul hier een geldig Nederlands mobiel telefoonnummer in.",
        postalcodeNL: "Vul hier een geldige postcode in.",
        bankaccountNL: "Vul hier een geldig bankrekeningnummer in.",
        giroaccountNL: "Vul hier een geldig gironummer in.",
        bankorgiroaccountNL: "Vul hier een geldig bank- of gironummer in."
    });

    function addCustomMessages() {
        $("#password_confirm").rules("add", {
            required: true,
            equalTo: "#password",
            messages: {
                required: "Herhaal uw wachtwoord",
                equalTo: "Enter the same password as above"
            }
        });
    }

}(jQuery));
```

still not working for me, someone who can help me with it?

Comment: You should include Jquery and MVC tags as well.

Comment: @ragatskynet you can add those tags, too :)

Comment: See the edited answer please. Do not for to accept if it helped you :)

Comment: @nvrtheless still not showing me a equalTo error message when i use different passwords

Answer (score 2):

When you use html helpers it will generate a `<input>` tag for you when cshtml parsed to html. So using `#password_confirm` as ID is not correct. If you want "password_confirm" to be ID of your input tag, then specify using an HTML attribute in HTML helper.

For example:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new{id="password_confirm"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add several attributes to the field in HTML, like this:

`@Html.PasswordFor(c => c.Password, new { id = "password-confirm"})`

This case the id of the field should be `password-confirm`.